# SSLSocket duplex close failed java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed while trying to connect to DB2 over TLS

Tags: java, ssl, jdbc, db2

I'm trying to understand why this error occurs:

```
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-07-04 12:08:30.668 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:497|SSLSocket duplex close failed (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Socket.java:1538)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:216)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:751)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bruteForceCloseInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:701)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.duplexCloseOutput(SSLSocketImpl.java:562)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.close(SSLSocketImpl.java:486)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.close(SSLSocketImpl.java:1034)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a0.j(a0.java:343)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.freeTransport_(b.java:5523)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.close_(a.java:455)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Agent.close(Agent.java:345)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:965)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:804)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:441)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:414)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:352)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:233)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:200)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:182)
        at com.example.MainApplication.main(MainApplication.java:36)}

)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-07-04 12:08:30.668 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1217|Closing output stream
Exception in sql: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlNonTransientConnectionException
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-20157, SQLSTATE=08004, SQLERRMC=WEBADMIN;QUIESCE DATABASE;;, DRIVER=4.25.13
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlNonTransientConnectionException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-20157, SQLSTATE=08004
```

The exception is thrown when I'm invoking getConnection() method of the DriverManager:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, properties);
```

I'm using Java 11.0.11 from Oracle (non-OpenJDK).

Answer (score 0):

Talk with your DBA team or whoever manages the database - you get this exception because someone (or some job) has put the database into a specific state that is used for maintenance activity.

Normally this is a temporary situation, and the database (or Db2-instance) needs to be brought back to normal mode by an [unquiesce](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-unquiesce) action, when the maintenance activity is completed.  After the unquiesce action, your connection should complete as normal.

The SQLCODE (-20157)  and SQLERRMC ( SQLERRMC=WEBADMIN;QUIESCE DATABASE;) that are in the message tell you the cause of this exception.

Lookup [SQL20157N](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql20000-sql20249#sql20157n) in the docs to get the detailed explanation.